# AngularJS ng-model not working with input[radio]

Tags: angularjs

Now that I have markup like this:

```
<form role="form" name="mprForm" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="MprFormController" novalidate> 
  ...     
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gender">性别</label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <label class="radio" for="genderf">
          <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" name="gender" value="0" id="genderf" data-toggle="radio" checked flat-radio>
          女
        </label>
        <label class="radio" for="genderm">
          <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" name="gender" value="1" id="genderm" data-toggle="radio" flat-radio>
          男
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- 性别选择 -->

  ... 

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="mprForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">提交</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- 提交按钮 --> 
</form> <!-- 修改信息表单 -->
```

And the controller's code:

```
/**
 *  修改用户资料表单（基本资料）
 */
.controller('MprFormController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.uidata = {};
  $scope.submit = function() {
    console.log($scope.user.gender)
  }
}])
```

There are no other scopes between the controller's scope and ng-model's scope. But when I click on the button, it outputs `undefined`. It is supposed to be 1 or 0. And when I use inpect tool to set breakpoints, I see `undefined` in the watcher, too.
I am using angular.js `1.2.10rc3`. It is a comprehensive framework, but WTF?

Answer (score 0):

`user` object is not defined, so `user.gender` property gives `undefined` define `user.gender` instead of using 'checked' in the radio button

```
$scope.user = {
   gender: 0
}
```

It will work fine

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/18xuzdEQGZ1rkl5FCUkI?p=preview